# ADA failure: These elements are focusable but either invisible or obscured by another element

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a bootstrap-based site that consistently fails the google developer ADA check for "These elements are focusable but either invisible or obscured by another element". I cannot figure out why these 10 links fail. Below is on of the a tags with some context, but if you visit [www.pluscu.org](http://www.pluscu.org) you and run google's developer ADA audit, you can see all of them.

```
<address>
  <strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>Zappos Perky Plus Person</strong><br>
  Phone: 702.871.4746 x5957<br>
  Email: <a href="mailto:zappos@pluscu.org">zappos@pluscu.org</a>
</address>
```

Comment: in what way is the Ada programming language involved, are you using Gnoga or AWS?

Comment: @BrianDrummond the tag is maybe not appropriate here, but ADA in this question is referring to the [American Disabilities Act](https://adata.org/learn-about-ada) ... The OP wants to make his web site conform to their accessibility standards :)

Comment: @SunilD.: Thanks for clarifying; tags edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different ADA checker that will tell you the solution to your error/warning/etc.

Download Mozilla Firefox. Download/Install the AInspector plugin. Paste your site in the URL: [www.pluscu.org](http://www.pluscu.org). Run the evaluation.

You currently have 4 violations. One of them is in the Links, like you are talking about. You can click on them specifically to fix each one of them.

[image]